# Change color of a component inside a function dinamically

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the next component:

```
const DetailsInformation = () => {
    const [details, setDetails] = useState(null)
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        getDetails()
    }, [])
    
    const getDetails = async () => {
        await getData().then((details)=>{
            details.forEach((detail)=>{
                detail.posibles_valores.forEach((valor)=>{
                    valor.selected = false
                })
            })
            setDetails(filteredDetails)
        })
    }

    const getIconColor = (value) => {
        if(!value) return 'grey';
        return  Colors.primary
    } 

    const updateDetail = (nombre_detalle, detalle) => {
        let detailToUpdateIndex = details.findIndex(det => det.nombre.toLowerCase() == detalle.toLowerCase())
        let innerDetailToUpdateIndex = details[detailToUpdateIndex].posibles_valores.findIndex(valor => valor.valor_detalle.toLowerCase() == nombre_detalle.toLowerCase())
        let updatedDetails = details;
        updatedDetails[detailToUpdateIndex].posibles_valores[innerDetailToUpdateIndex].selected = !updatedDetails[detailToUpdateIndex].posibles_valores[innerDetailToUpdateIndex].selected
        updatedDetails[detailToUpdateIndex].posibles_valores[innerDetailToUpdateIndex].color = getIconColor(!updatedDetails[detailToUpdateIndex].posibles_valores[innerDetailToUpdateIndex].selected)

        
        setDetails(updatedDetails)
    }

    const generateDetailValues = (detail) => {
        let detailSelected = details.find(det => det.nombre.toLowerCase() == detail.toLowerCase())
        return (<View>
            {detailSelected.posibles_valores.map((detalle, index)=>(
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback key={detalle.valor_detalle} onPress={()=>{updateDetail(detalle.valor_detalle, detail, index)}}>
                    <View  style={{justifyContent:'space-between', marginHorizontal:30, alignItems:'center',   flex:1, flexDirection:'row'}}>
                <Text bold style={{fontSize:18, marginVertical:2, marginHorizontal:8, textAlign:'center'}}>{detalle.valor_detalle}</Text>
         <Icon type='AntDesign' name='checkcircle' style={{fontSize: 20, color:detalle.color}}/>
                </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            ))}
            </View>)
    }
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>List One</Text>
            <View>
            { details && generateDetailValues('list_one', details)}
            </View>
            <Text>List two</Text>
            <View>
           {details && generateDetailValues('list_two', details)}
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

In summary, I make an API call and after, I render the component returned by  "generateDetailValues", this component have a "onPress" function which changes the color of the icon inside the component.

The problem is when I'm press that touchable, the values of "details" change, but the color doesn't , that's because the "generateDetailValues" doesn't executed.

Any idea how I can make that function execute (in the render method) when "details" change?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

getIconColor always returns Colors.primary no matter what value you pass into the function, I guess this is why the color never changes.

I don't know how you your Color object works but it seems like it should depend on value in some way, e.g:

```
    const getIconColor = (value) => {
        if(!value) return 'grey';
        return  Colors.value.primary
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that function is returning the correct value, the problem is that the "generateDetailValues" function is only executed once but I don't know why.